# Google Places Autocomplete returning results in the wrong language

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

When searching the term "Queensland" in google places auto complete two of the results that come back are in the complete wrong languages. One returns in Japanese and the other in Korean. The language is explicitly set to english AU and the results that are returned are places in the state of Queensland Australia just in the wrong language. I would ask google support directly but it keeps directing me here.

This is the api call I'm making:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=queensland&key=[API KEY OMMITED]&components=country:AU&types=(regions)&language=en-AU`

And these are the results I am getting back:

- "Queensland, Australia"
- "Gold Coast QLD, Australia"
- "Australia, Queensland, バーリー・ヘッズ" (Burleigh Heads)
- "Australia, Queensland, 워릭" (Warwick)

I'm not sure if this is a bug in the api or there is an issue with the call I'm making.

Comment: The same happens with other languages such as `en` or `fr` so I think this is a data issue. You should contact Google because we can't deal with data issues. You can report the problem in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188872) and cross-link this question and the issue you create.

Comment: Thanks @MrUpsidown I've done that [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/179822442)